# Running linux from Termux (PRoot) vs running Linux from image (chroot, apps like Linux Deploy or Linux Installer)

Tags: linux, android, root

I have a phone that has DP output over USB-C, hence it can be used with secondary display almost as a fully fledged "laptop", but the limiting factor is android system that is not very suited to running desktop applications, or even desktop-like environment.

But it was made possible to install Linux distros on rooted phones first, with apps like Linux Deploy, and now it is also possible to install Linux using PRoot apps like Termux.

In fact I have installed Ubuntu 18.04 XFCE through AnLinux+Termux in userspace and I am typing this question from it, but there are certain downsides: I can't figure out how to add keyboard layout through standard means, xrdp doesn't seem to work as it encounters certain problems with dbus, the whole system is quite slow and unresponsive, even though it is not running into memory or CPU limits, but it also might be slowed down by VNC.

Now, it is also possible to root my phone and run Linux with root environment like Linux Deploy, but what does it change?

If I run Linux from root environment, would it make the system more responsive, or make certain things like xrdp work reliably?

What does change whether the Linux subsystem running on Android has root access or not? Do they share the same kernel that way, or does Linux run in a sort of virtual environment? Would using modified android kernel provide some advantages to Linux running in root environment? Is there any gain in rooting Android phone and running Linux "natively", as opposed to running it through Termux?

Comment: you can't run linux "natively" with Deploy. it's just a chroot container on top of android sharing android kernel, which is very device specific and contains proprietary vendor specific drivers (most likely violating GPL btw). ubports maintains Ubuntu Touch for some smartphones that might come a full linux more close, but still rely on underlaying android. so its just a personal preference

Comment: But what is the difference, then? And also, does installing custom Android kernel means Linux would also use it, so is there advantage of running PRoot vs chroot with modified kernel?

Comment: the [difference](https://wiki.termux.com/wiki/PRoot) is isolated [namespace](https://www.toptal.com/linux/separation-anxiety-isolating-your-system-with-linux-namespaces) separation. the former one doesn't require root privileges on the device itself